# can we upload alexa training using an API?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

i want to add utterances/slot values in the skill, without using Amazon Developer console (i.e. from my project using an API provided by amazon for uploading alexa training set). 
Is there any API available that could do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the [ASK CLI](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html). If you're just trying to update the skill's model, you can either use the [deploy](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#deploy-command) command with the `--target model` option or the [update-model](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#update-model-subcommand) command.